# Calculate the percent occurrence of a variable in multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:1000, each = 35), year = rep(1980:2014,times = 1000),month.id = sample(c(1:4,8:10,12),35*1000,replace = T))
```

The data frame has a 1000 locations X 35 years of data for a variable called `month.id` which is basically the month of a year. For each  year, I want to calculate percent occurrence of each month. For e.g. for 1980,

```
month.vec <- df[df$year == 1980,]
table(month.vec$month.id)
1   2   3   4   8   9  10  12 
106 132 116 122 114 130 141 139
```

To calculate the percent occurrence of months:

```
table(month.vec$month.id)/length(month.vec$month.id) * 100
1    2    3    4    8    9   10   12 
10.6 13.2 11.6 12.2 11.4 13.0 14.1 13.9
```

I want to have a table something like this:

```
    year month percent
    1980   1    10.6
    1980   2    13.2
    1980   3    11.6
    1980   4    12.2
    1980   5    NA
    1980   6    NA
    1980   7    NA
    1980   8    11.4    
    1980   9    13
    1980   10   14.1
    1980   11   NA
    1980   12   13.9
```

Since, months 5,6,7,11 are missing, I just want to add the additional rows with NAs for those months. If possible, I would
like a dplyr solution to something like this:

```
   library(dplyr)
   df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(percentage.contri = table(month.id)/length(month.id)*100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
# To get month as integer use (or add as.integer to mutate):
# df$month.id <- as.integer(df$month.id)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    group_by(year, month.id) %>% 
    # Count occurrences per year & month
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    # Get percent per month (year number is calculated with sum(n))
    mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100) %>%
    # Fill in missing months
    complete(year, month.id = 1:12, fill = list(percent = 0)) %>%
    select(year, month.id, percent)
```

> ```
>     year month.id percent
>    <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
>  1  1980     1.00    10.6
>  2  1980     2.00    13.2
>  3  1980     3.00    11.6
>  4  1980     4.00    12.2
>  5  1980     5.00     0  
>  6  1980     6.00     0  
>  7  1980     7.00     0  
>  8  1980     8.00    11.4
>  9  1980     9.00    13.0
> 10  1980    10.0     14.1
> 11  1980    11.0      0  
> 12  1980    12.0     13.9
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution:

```
tab <- table(month.vec$year, factor(month.vec$month.id, levels = 1:12))/length(month.vec$month.id) * 100
dfnew <- as.data.frame(tab)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dfnew
>    Var1 Var2 Freq
> 1  1980    1 10.6
> 2  1980    2 13.2
> 3  1980    3 11.6
> 4  1980    4 12.2
> 5  1980    5  0.0
> 6  1980    6  0.0
> 7  1980    7  0.0
> 8  1980    8 11.4
> 9  1980    9 13.0
> 10 1980   10 14.1
> 11 1980   11  0.0
> 12 1980   12 13.9
> ```

---

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(month.vec)[, .N, by = .(year, month.id)
                 ][.(year = 1980, month.id = 1:12), on = .(year, month.id)
                   ][, N := 100 * N/sum(N, na.rm = TRUE)][]
```